# In Watership Down what was so bad about Efrafa

Tags: watership-down

First: I never saw the entire movie, just bits and pieces.

I know a rabbit named "Blackavar" wanted to escape Efrafa and so did some does (female rabbits). It's just, I'm not sure exactly why they wanted to get away.

Was it just because General Woundwart was a jerk (because he was), or was the warren in itself bad?

Answer (score 10):

Efrafa was over-crowded, and the rabbits were oppressed. They were treated badly, and the does were forced to obey horrible rules: they weren't allowed to reproduce, and were forced to mate with superior males that order them to. That is why they wanted to get out of Efrafa. There's more info here: https://www.shmoop.com/watership-down/efrafan-rabbits.html